# Using cmd tools when hosting a site

Tags: django, hosting, cmd, webfaction

Do webapp hosting sites such as webfaction.com support the use of cmd tools such as pdftk and pdftotext? For example, if in my django-powered site I do something like

```
subprocess.Popen("pdftk.exe....")
```

would this still work when I begin hosting the site?

Comment: In what context do those applications run?  On the server, or on the client side.  I would warn you about either, in case of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I would  assume that they would be running on the server side. How would I get the pdftk.exe to the client? And what security vulnerabilites might arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On webfaction at least, you can install such tools in your own directory and then call them.  If your process starts hogging memory, it may get killed off.  For example see this [thread](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=2652) on the forum.